# How to extract a list of URLs from specific domain?

Tags: firefox, web-scraping, extract

I'm using Firefox 53, and have Scrapbook X and want to save a lot of pages using the Save Multiple URLs feature, but before I do that, I want to extract a specific list of URLs without having to do so manually.

The site I'm looking at extracting data from is www.address-data.co.uk - namely [this page](https://address-data.co.uk/postcode-area-EH).

What I want to do is extract only the URLs and subpages within that page but not the privacy policy or contact us page and all the sub-pages with the EH postcodes.

Is there a way to do this online, or any tool for Mac OS X that can find all related URLs before I copy them into Scrapbook's Save Multiple URLs (where I save them in a subfolder of Scrapbook)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that [EH45](https://address-data.co.uk/postcode-district-EH45) is typical of those you want to extract from the page you mentioned. Like its siblings it's of the form `https://address-data.co.uk/postcode-district-EH<postcode number>`.

This means that you can make a complete list of the urls if you have a list of the numbers, or of the postcodes.

My main difficulty in answering is that I don't know what tools (especially programming tools) you might have at your disposal. I will assume only that you have, or can obtain, access to an editor that can do macros or that can edit columns. On Windows I would use Emerald (ow known as Crimson).

Then copy the *contents* of the table in the EH page (not the table headings) and remove everything except the first column. Finally, prepend every item in the column with 'https://address-data.co.uk/postcode-district-'.

PS: This might also be a good question to put on SuperUser.